# Certain groups not visible SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, groups

I have a site collection with approx 1800 groups altogether, however when looking through the groups under 'people and groups' site settings, only ~1100 are visible. The groups that aren't shown are only visible by directly typing their exact name when adding permissions or I've obtained a complete list through PowerShell. Does anyone know why SharePoint wouldnt be showing all groups? It doesn't seem to correlate with the number of users in the groups.

Thanks

Comment: You had me until the last line. What do the "number of users in the groups" have to do with the problem of not all SharePoint permission groups being listed in the UI? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry Phil - I'm stating that I don't think it has anything to do with it. The number of users in the groups varies greatly, but it doesn't seem to relate to which groups dont show in UI. Just trying to state all the facts.